# Client cannot connect to server on a different machine -- solved

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

## It turns out the problem is not on my end....the firewall from the Linux server I used refuses to connect...

I am writing a client/server model, my goal is client and server can run on different machines, however, connect() in my client always return -1.
Ping works for both directions between two machines.
The code works on the same machine.

client.c

```
    int fd;
    int PORT;
    char IP[20];
    struct hostent *server;
    printf("Enter Port Number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PORT);
    printf("Enter IP Address: \n");
    scanf("%s", IP);
    server = gethostbyname(IP);

    socklen_t len;
    struct sock_opts *ptr;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    connect(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)); //connection timed out
```

server.c

```
 int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen, n;
 int PORT;
 printf("Enter Port Number: \n");
 scanf("%d", &PORT);
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 char buffer[128];

 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
 bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
 listen(sockfd,5);
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

output: 
./client

```
Enter Port Number:
5544
Enter IP Address
192.168.1.56
ERROR: Connection timed out
```

./server

```
Enter Port Number:
5544
Server will then time out because client is not able to connect.
```

Comment: Call `perror` to get a more detailed error description. If you need further help please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include your exact input.

Comment: I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things can help you.

Firstyl, you can use some tools like wireshark or tcpdump to see how the sockets going.

Secondly, the connect return value can give many informations, you can see [this](http://www.on-time.com/rtos-32-docs/rtip-32/reference-manual/socket-api/connect.htm).

And the next time please remember to give a complete code which can show your problem.

Comment: Oh I did not post the code, let me modify the question.

Comment: That should probably be a comment, no?

Comment: @ Gerhardh As he edited his question, I edited my answer. And my old answer is relatively match his old question, I think it's not only a comment.

Comment: "connection timed out" is the error message..showing the server does not respond. I will take a look at Wireshark and tcpdump, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how the server is timing out. If not interrupted and the socket is blocking, the server should pause at `accept()` forever if it is not receiving any connections. After a quick look and based on the behavior you reported, the server code is terminating first, and thus the client becomes connectionless.

`newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);`

This is where your server is going wrong. You didn't initialize the `clilen` before passing it to `accept()`. Your server code may probably be expecting this before a call to `accept()`

```
/* .... */

clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

/* .... */
```

Comment: hey I forgot to post the code for initializing clilen, good eye!

Comment: but that's not causing the problem, as I said, my code works on a single machine, so there should be nothing wrong with the setup of sockets. And it's my client connect() returning error first, the server is connected all the time.

Comment: @Ashley It did not even work for once on different machines, or it failed when you tried to run your server code repeatedly? Because ports are not released as soon as code terminates and you are having no checks for bind(), even if bind() failed server still continues to run and OS assigns the ephemeral port to the unbound socket

Comment: It never worked. I have error message on every step so I would know if things like bind failed, I did not post the debug code here.  And I use a different port every time I rerun the program..